# Isolate the last octet from an IP address and put it in a variable

Tags: regex, shell, awk, sed, ip-address

The following script:

```
IP=`ifconfig en0 inet | grep inet | sed 's/.*inet *//; s/ .*//'`
```

isolates the IP address from `ipconfig` command and puts it into the variable `$IP`.
How can I now isolate the last octet from the said IP address and put it in a second variable - `$CN`

for instance:

$IP = 129.66.128.72    $CN = 72 or $IP = 129.66.128.133   $CN = 133...

Comment: Its better to not use old and outdated back-tics, but instead use parentheses like this `IP=$(ifconfig.....)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortcut:

```
read IP CN < <(exec ifconfig en0 | awk '/inet / { t = $2; sub(/.*[.]/, "", t); print $2, t }')
```

Comment: `<( ... )` is non-standard and not supported by all shells.

Answer (score 14):

Use "cut" command with . delimiter:

```
IP=129.66.128.72
CN=`echo $IP | cut -d . -f 4`
```

CN now contains the last octet.

Comment: You can shorten it some to:`CN=$(cut -d. -f4 <<<$IP)`

Comment: `<<<` is non-standard and not supported by all shells.

Answer (score 10):

In BASH you can use:

```
ip='129.66.128.72'
cn="${ip##*.}"
echo $cn
72
```

Or using sed for non BASH:

```
cn=`echo "$ip" | sed 's/^.*\.\([^.]*\)$/\1/'`
echo $cn
72
```

Using `awk`

```
cn=`echo "$ip" | awk -F '\\.' '{print $NF}'`
```

Comment: Shorter using awk `cn=$(awk -F. '$0=$4' <<< $ip)`

Comment: @Jidder: I believe only BASH supports `<<<` that's why I used pipes in non BASH solutions.

Comment: Oh okay,didn't know it was specific to bash, is `$()` bash specific as well ?

Comment: No, [`$(...)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03) is in the POSIX standard.

Comment: Ah that is correct, thank for correcting @chepner me. Always helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I would not use `ifconfig` to get the IP, rather use this solution, since it gets the IP needed to get to internet regardless of interface.

```
IP=$(ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk '{print $NF;exit}')
```

and to get last octet:

```
last=$(awk -F. '{print $NF}' <<< $IP)
```

or get the last octet directly:

```
last=$(ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk -F. '{print $NF;exit}')
```

Comment: This doesn't work (any more?) because a UID prints after the IP.  Like this: "8.8.8.8 via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0 src 192.168.1.85 uid 1000 
    cache 
"